# Formatting PHP, what works more efficiently?

Tags: php, code-quality, code-formatting

I was just wondering what makes PHP work faster. I have a few methods that I always go and do, but that only improves the way I can read it, but how about the interpreter?

#### Should I include the curly braces when there is only one statement to run?

```
if(...){
    echo "test";
}
# Or..
if(...)
    echo "test";
=== Which should be used?
```

#### I have also found http://beta.phpformatter.com/, and I find the following settings to be good, but are they?

> #### Indentation:
>
> Indentation style: `{K&R (One true brace style)}`
> Indent with: `{Tabs}`
> Starting indentation: `[1]`
> Indentation: `[1]`
>
> #### Common:
>
> `[x]` Remove all comments
> `[x]` Remove empty lines
> `[x]` Align assignments statements nicely
> `[ ]` Put a comment with the condition after if, while, for, foreach, declare and catch statements
>
> #### Improvement:
>
> `[x]` Remove lines with just a semicolon (;)
> `[x]` Make normal comments (//) from perl comments (#)
> `[x]` Make long opening tag (<?php) from short one (<?)
>
> #### Brackets:
>
> `[x]` Space inside brackets `- ( )`
> `[x]` Space inside empty brackets `- ( )`
> `[x]` Space inside block brackets `- [ ]`
> `[x]` Space inside empty block brackets `- [ ]`

#### Tiny var names:

often I go through my code and change `$var1` to `$a`, `$var2` to $b and so on. I do include comments at the start of the file to show to me what each letter(s) mean..

#### Final note:

So am I doing the right thing with the curly braces and the settings?
Are there any great tips that help it run faster?

Comment: Code formatting will not make your code faster.

Comment: @Mchl : What I mean is formatting makes it easer for me to read, does that come at a cost for the interpreter to process it?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: And even if it did, it would never have remotely enough impact to justify hurting readability.

Comment: btw: With my files, I understand every $A-F0-9, $_0 $_1 .. $_9 $a $a0 $a1 .. $ff, so when if I ever reach 255/ff I will simply go and rewrite the whole file, as I have a max of 255 hex codes to remember I usually just read the hex as what I have it mapped to, Okay this did take a while to get used to though its now just a habit.

Comment: I also some times run `$_=array();$_["a1"]="Var 1";$_["1a"]="Var 2";`

Answer (score 6):

You should always code with legibility in mind.  If a certain portion of code has performance issues, you optimize it as necessary.  This may likely lead to less legible code.  In which case you provide extra explanations in comments.

As far as formatting is concerned, it doesn't have an impact on performance.  I avoid those bracketless `if` statements as they are fragile and somewhat obscure.  Thus, making your code potentially easier to break and harder to understand.

Comment: +1 - I NEVER write if statements (or other conditional statements) without braces or indentation. They make codes vulnerable to mistakes and bugs.

Answer (score 4):

> Indentation style: `{K&R (One true brace style)}`

Subjective: choose one and stick to it throught your project

> Indent with: `{Tabs}`

Subjective: 'spaces' vs 'tabs' debat will never end

> Starting indentation: `[1]`

Why not 0?

> Indentation: `[1]`

One tab, but at least two spaces

> `[x]` Remove all comments

Nonsense.

> `[x]` Remove empty lines

Nonsense.

> `[x]` Align assignments statements nicely

As long as 'nicely' is really nice

> `[ ]` Put a comment with the condition after if, while, for, foreach, declare and catch statements

A helpful thing if you end up with too convoluted statements. Refactoring into smaller methods is usally better way to improve readibility.

> #### Improvement:
>
> `[x]` Remove lines with just a semicolon (;)

Makes sense

> `[x]` Make normal comments (//) from perl comments (#)

Both work.

> `[x]` Make long opening tag (<?php) from short one (<?)
>
> #### Brackets:

Makes sense.

> `[x]` Space inside brackets `- ( )`
> `[x]` Space inside empty brackets `- ( )`
> `[x]` Space inside block brackets `- [ ]`
> `[x]` Space inside empty block brackets `- [ ]`

Subjective.

> #### Tiny var names:
>
> often I go through my code and change `$var1` to `$a`, `$var2` to $b and so on. I do >include comments at the start of the file to show to me what each letter(s) mean..

Why would you do that? It reduces readibility, and you gain nothing.

Comment: I'm especially confused by the `$var1`/`$a` stuff... *both* are terrible variable names!

Comment: I'm assuming that `$var1` is meant to symbolize `$aMeaningfulVariableName` in this case.

Comment: @Dean : @Mchl Is correct, and $a is meant to be only for minimizing the code.

Comment: @Michl : Humm, what about the first question on my post? about the closing curly braces if there is only one statement though a few statements require them like switch.

Comment: @JamesM-SiteGen: Personally I think it is acceptable in one case only: `if($conditionToBreakLoop) continue;` or `break;`

Comment: @Mchl : So you are saying that `if(!$a)flush();` would not be acceptable? flush is just an example.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. The difference is that 'break;' or 'contiunue;' are in fuct jump instructions, so there is no risk of somebody adding another instruction below and wondering why it's not being executed.

Comment: Humm, so you are saying that even if there is only one command to run I should have {...}??

Comment: That's what I'm saying.

Comment: The very fact that they are all **options** means that by definition they are all subjective!

Answer (score 2):

Use formatting that is easy for humans to read.  The [Speed Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Speed_optimization) resources I've found suggest that compiling PHP will make it faster.  Other resources suggest that the interpreter will cache the pages, and the cached pages will be optimized.

What this means is that it's not worth your time to do this manually.  First, it makes the code unreadable, and second, the interpreter will do this for you, so all you'll accomplish is making the code unmaintainable.

Here is a Stack Overflow Question, [PHP Source Code Whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747373/php-source-code-whitespace), that suggests there are very minute speed gains.  However, I don't think it's worth the tradeoff of readibility for very little gain.

I suggest that you instead focus on growing the product, adding more features, and focusing on your business goals.  You'll reap more rewards by focusing on those goals instead of over-optimizing.